# Assign files to each other

Tags: shell, loops, bioinformatics

I want to assign two files as input files. Here an example:

```
directory1
AB001.txt
AB002.txt
AB003.txt
....

directory2
AB001.fasta
AB002.fasta
AB003.fasta
....
```

So, I want to loop through more than 5000 *.txt files with a corresponding *.fasta file (always with matching prefixes). The command that should be executed for all *.txt files is:

```
program -i1 AB001.txt -i2 AB001.fasta > output AB001.aln
program -i1 AB002.txt -i2 AB002.fasta > output AB002.aln
program -i1 AB003.txt -i2 AB003.fasta > output AB003.aln
.
.
.
```

How can I do that with a shell script. I am still a newbe, but I would like to learn more about simple shell scripting, and of course I would like to use the loop, so that I don't have to do the command for each file manually.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop with parameter expansion.

```
#! /bin/bash
for txt in directory1/*.txt ; do
    name=${txt##*/}         # Delete up to the last slash.
    name=${name%.txt}       # Remove `.txt` at the end.
    fasta=directory2/$name.fasta
    program -i1 "$txt" -i2 "$fasta" > ouptut "$name".aln
done
```

Note that `> output AB001.aln` will redirect the output of the program to a file named `output` and pass the `AB001.aln` as a parameter to the program.